# Strange output of leaflet vector tiles object

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I made some vector tiles layer on my leaflet map. Everything is working good, but i want to get some object from this `layer._tiles`. The problem is when i log on console this object layer._tiles I've got a strange object and I can't make anything with this - for example I can't log `layer._tiles[0]`
I made screenshot of this strange object, and attached.

How to get something from this? for example object of(`67:40:canvas...`) or only canvas from this?

[image]

Comment: Which plugin are you using for displaying vector tiles?

Comment: this: http://www.sumbera.com/gist/js/leaflet/canvas/L.CanvasTiles.js